# Finding the closest possible values from two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Let's suppose you have two existing dictionaries `A` and `B`

If you already choose an initial two items from dictionaries `A` and `B` with values `A1 = 1.0` and `B1 = 2.0`, respectively, is there any way to find any two different existing items in the dictionaries `A` and `B` that each have different values (i.e. `A2` and `B2`) from `A1` and `B1`, and would also minimize the value `(A2-A1)**2 + (B2-B1)**2`?

The number of items in the dictionary is unfixed and could exceed 100,000.

Edit - This is important: the keys for `A` and `B` are the same, but the values corresponding to those keys in `A` and `B` are different. A particular choice of key will yield an ordered pair (A1,B1) that is different from any other possible order pair (A2,B2)—different keys have different order pairs. For example, both `A` and `B` will have the key `3,4` and this will yield a value of `1.0` for dict `A` and `2.0` for `B`. This one key will then be compared to every other key possible to find the other ordered pair (i.e. both the key and values of the items in `A` and `B`) that minimizes the squared differences between them.

Comment: Your question is not complete.  Do you care what the corresponding keys are to A2 & B2?  Do you just need the values?  If A2 & B2 appear more than once, do you need to return a list of all keys?  Ozgur (who seems to have deleted his comment) is on the right track though, you will be sorting by values.

Comment: @MaxWen I do not necessarily specify what the keys themselves are as they may vary. They will usually be ordered pairs of the form `j,k` where j and k are integers, but that is not a strict requirement for my question. A more general approach would be appreciated. The main importance is finding items in the dictionaries with close—but not the same—values. A return of the two keys from `A` and `B` with closest value to `A1` and `B1` is sought. Yea, I was thinking some sort of sorting method would be necessary, but any particularly efficient methods would be very helpful.

Comment: @MaxWen To add, all keys in the dictionary are already known. Although the item (i.e. both its key and value) with the value closest to A1 and B1 as specified above is sought. I also made an edit, so that no choice of keys can give the same two values as both A2 and B2 since the keys considered during a comparison are the same. I can provide an example if that would be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a specialized data structure, not a standard Python dictionary. Look up quad-tree or kd-tree. You are effectively minimizing the Euclidean distance between two points (your objective function is just a square root away from Euclidean distance, and your dictionary A is storing x-coordinates, B y-coordinates.). Computational-geometry people have been studying this for years.

Well, maybe I am misreading your question and making it harder than it is. Are you saying that you can pick *any* value from A and *any* value from B, regardless of whether their keys are the same? For instance, the pick from A could be K:V (3,4):2.0, and the pick from B could be (5,6):3.0? Or does it have to be (3,4):2.0 from A and (3,4):6.0 from B? If the former, the problem is easy: just run through the values from A and find the closest to A1; then run through the values from B and find the closest to B1. If the latter, my first paragraph was the right answer.

Your comment says that the harder problem is the one you want to solve, so here is a little more. Sedgewick's slides explain how the static grid, the 2d-tree, and the quad-tree work. http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/99GeometricSearch.pdf . Slides 15 through 29 explain mainly the 2d-tree, with 27 through 29 covering the solution to the nearest-neighbor problem. Since you have the constraint that the point the algorithm finds must share neither x- nor y-coordinate with the query point, you might have to implement the algorithm yourself or modify an existing implementation. One alternative strategy is to use a kNN data structure (k nearest neighbors, as opposed to the single nearest neighbor), experiment with k, and hope that your chosen k will always be large enough to find at least one neighbor that meets your constraint.

Comment: It is the latter—the keys must be the same. It is essentially a non-uniform 2-dimensional grid on which I am trying to find the nearest point on the grid to an initially specified one.

Comment: Got it. I added a third paragraph to my answer.

Comment: You have almost understood my case exactly. This is a minor point, but for each ordered pair (An,Bn), only Bn has to be different from every other ordered pair's Bm. Another ordered pair (Am,Bm) may or may not have Am = An, but Bn != Bm always. I still am reading through the link you sent me, but thought I would clarify this point.

Comment: It's a slightly odd representation to make two separate dicts—one for each of my dimensions—but it seemed like the best method for a non-uniform adaptive grid, namely because there are separate dicts with the same keys as the independent variables but holding values associated to dependent variables. I'll have to look into the kd-tree/quad-tree structures you have mentioned and see if they are suitable for my purposes, especially because the current method is already quite computationally-intensive.